# Inspect Rails Session Cookie in Google Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session-cookies, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible using the Chrome Resource Inspector to view the value of my Rails session that is stored in a cookie? It seems to be encoded somehow, as it's value is just an incoherent string of alphanumeric characters.

I just want to be able to inspect what the values are as I debug requests.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blogpost](http://techbrahmana.blogspot.ru/2012/03/rails-cookie-handling-serialization-and.html) answers your question. It is not so easy to decode as you might think :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Rails 4 this is no longer possible. Session Cookies are encrypted nowadays. More Information on this can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html).

Comment: Correct that nowadays its encrypted using the EncryptedCookieStore; but you can still decrypt the underlying values if your secret_key_base value in config/secrets.yml is known (which for local dev is known)